# How to show hidden element with .click function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to click on an img (a down arrow) to display a container and then click on a div (a "X") to hide the same container. The issue I am having is maintaining the css property of the container.

If I keep the display: inline-block setting, the entire container shows before I click the img, however if I change to display: none and don't include $(".create").css({"display":"inline-block"}) in my jquery code, the entire container appears floated to the left.

I've bodged it by using jquery to change the css of the container on a click, but I wonder if there's a simpler way of doing this.

Previously I have set the container to display: none and then using jquery, changed it to display: inline-block so that the parent div's text-align: center instruction makes the original container appear in the middle of the page.

I expect the create container to be hidden until I click on the image element, and then to hide again once I click on the exit div.

I have no idea if any of this code is written poorly or not, I suspect so!

```js
$(function() {
  $(".arrow-1").click(function() {
    $(".create").show(500);
    $(".create").css({
      "display": "inline-block"
    })
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".exit").click(function() {
    $(".create").hide(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.create-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.create {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.exit {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  border: white 3px solid;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="arrows">
 <div class="arrow-imgs">
  <a href="#"><img class="arrow-1" src="https://monasteryeventcenter.com/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home/white-down-arrow-png-2.png"></a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="create-container">
  <div class="create">
    <div class="exit"><a href="#">X</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see any element in your html that has the class `arrow-1`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen my apologies, I'm updated it now

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

To simply show or hide an element using jQuery you can use

`$(".create-container").attr("hidden", true)`

**Before edit:**

Correct me if im wrong but it seems as if you're trying to display some sort of tooltip upon click.

```
<style>
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Taken from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

You can also add a little 'x' in that container that will hide it

`$("#xbutton").on("click", () => $("#container).attr("hidden", true));`

I hope this is what you were aiming for, apologies if not.

Comment: Hi @OmarM25, thanks for the reply. This is kind of what I'm after yes. But I don't want a hover function - I want to display a container by clicking an element (img) and hide the same container by clicking a different element (div). The img is a down arrow that is part of a navbar - in much the same way that a link in a navbar shows new info when clicked, I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Right so instead of the ```:hover``` css part, you can put those styles in a class you choose, and inside your ```.on("click", () => ``` function, you can add your class, a quick example:

```
.shown {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and inside your JS it will be:

```
$("#xbutton").on("click", () => $("#container).removeClass("shown"))
// If you want to show it just do .addClass("shown")
```
Hope this is what you were aiming for :)